# Desktop site's inner pages do not redirect to corresponding mobile page on phone

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I have a PHP site with which automatically redirects to its mobile site when viewed from a mobile phone. But I have come across that it only works for the home page, but not the rest of the pages.

When I access "www.abcd.com" from my phone it redirects to "m.abcd.com".
But when I try "www.abcd.com/about-us", it does not redirect to "m.abcd.com/about-us" but to "m.abcd.com" which is the home page.

How can I fix the rest of the desktop pages to redirect to their corresponding pages when accessed on smartphone? Any htaccess fix?

Comment: This question is too vague to really answer. What framework are you using? What is causing the redirect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

There will be some code within the index page that will redirect to m.abcd.com depending on the user agent. You will simply need to copy this code to the rest of the pages, or include it in some shared code for all the pages.